# Duplicate records in main form , subform and subsubform

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I struggle with below issue i googling for this issue several nights and i found a code but need to help

The issue is i need to duplicate records in main form , sub form and "subsubform" 3 levels deep

I found code in below link

https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/duplicate-data-in-form-its-subform-and-subsubform.3483545/#post-14289062

but unfortunately this post since 2008 I think its from archive files

anyway
i try this code in my database and its works for duplicate records in main form and subform but duplicate first record for "subsubform" only

and give runtime error as following :
Run time error 3078:
The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input
table or query. Make sure it exists and that the name is spelled
correctly.

My knowledge in vba very limited i am a very bigger in VBA so that i need your help

what I need

- fix runtime error 3078
- complete duplicate records in "subsubform"

Thanks in advance
kindly find below code

```
Private Sub cmdDuplicatePHIP_Click()
'Purpose: Duplicate the main form record and related records in the subform

Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim rstT2 As DAO.Recordset 'TRD_RDLog
Dim rstT2A As DAO.Recordset 'TRD_RDLog
Dim rstT3 As DAO.Recordset 'TFP_PHIPDtl
Dim rstT3A As DAO.Recordset 'TFP_PHIPDtl

Dim IngT1PK As Long ' current PK TRD_RDTrial
Dim IngT2PK As Long ' current PK TRD_RDLog
Dim IngT3PK As Long ' current PK TFP_PHIPDtl

Dim IngT1NewFK As Long ' new FK TRD_RDTrial
Dim IngT2NewFK As Long ' new FK TRD_RDLog
Dim IngT3NewFK As Long ' new FK TFP_PHIPDtl

Dim strSql As String 'SQL statement.
Dim strSql_S As String 'SQL statement.
Dim strSql_A As String 'SQL statement.
Dim msg As String

'records added
Dim intRC_CD As Integer 'TRD_RDTrial
Dim intRC_CS As Integer 'TRD_RDLog
Dim intRC_CA As Integer 'TFP_PHIPDtl

'Save and edits first
If Me.Dirty Then
Me.Dirty = False
End If

Set db = CurrentDb

'Make sure there is a record to duplicate.
If Me.NewRecord Then
MsgBox "Select the record to duplicate."
Else

'Duplicate the main record: add to form's clone.
'in TRD_RDTrial 1st table
IngT1PK = Me.TRPK

With Me.RecordsetClone
.AddNew
!TrialDate = Me.TrialDate
!TrialBy = Me.TrialBy
!QC = Me.QC
'etc for other fields.
.Update

intRC_CD = intRC_CD + 1

'Save the primary key value, to use as the foreign key for the related records.

.Bookmark = .LastModified
IngT1NewFK = !TRPK
End With

'Duplicate the related records in TRD_RDLog 2nd table
'Select all records in TRD_RDLog

strSql_S = " SELECT TDPK, TRPK, RDCode, Kitchen, TrialPurpose, PHIPNetWt, ItemTrialNotes, SampleApproval, SampleApprovalDate, SampleApprovalNotes, RecipeDate, Notes"
strSql_S = strSql_S & " FROM [TRD_RDLog];"
Set rstT2A = db.OpenRecordset(strSql_S)

'Select the records to duplicate
strSql_S = " SELECT TDPK, RDCode, Kitchen, TrialPurpose, PHIPNetWt, ItemTrialNotes, SampleApproval, SampleApprovalDate, SampleApprovalNotes, RecipeDate, Notes"
strSql_S = strSql_S & " FROM [TRD_RDLog]"
strSql_S = strSql_S & " WHERE TRPK = " & IngT1PK & ";"
Set rstT2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSql_S)

'check for empty recordset
If Not rstT2.BOF And Not rstT2.EOF Then
rstT2.MoveLast
rstT2.MoveFirst

Do While Not rstT2.EOF
'save PK
IngT2PK = rstT2!TDPK

'add new record
With rstT2A
.AddNew
!TRPK = IngT1NewFK
!RDCode = Nz(rstT2!RDCode, "")
!Kitchen = Nz(rstT2!Kitchen, "")
!TrialPurpose = Nz(rstT2!TrialPurpose, "")
!PHIPNetWt = Nz(rstT2!PHIPNetWt, "")
!ItemTrialNotes = Nz(rstT2!ItemTrialNotes, "")
!SampleApproval = Nz(rstT2!SampleApproval, "")
!SampleApprovalDate = Nz(rstT2!SampleApprovalDate, "")
!SampleApprovalNotes = Nz(rstT2!SampleApprovalNotes, "")
!RecipeDate = Nz(rstT2!RecipeDate, "")
!Notes = Nz(rstT2!Notes, "")

'etc for other fields.
.Update

intRC_CS = intRC_CS + 1

'get new PK
.Bookmark = .LastModified
IngT2NewFK = !TDPK ' new PK
End With


'Duplicate the related records in TFP_PHIPDtl (3rd table)

strSql_A = "SELECT IRF, TDPK, RawCode, Unit, PQty"
strSql_A = strSql_A & " FROM [TFP_PHIPDtl]"
Set rstT3A = db.OpenRecordset(strSql_A)
    
'Duplicate the related records in TFP_PHIPDtl (3rd table)

strSql_A = "SELECT IRF, RawCode, Unit, PQty"
strSql_A = strSql_A & " FROM [TFP_PHIPDtl]"
strSql_A = strSql_A & " WHERE TDPK = " & IngT2PK & ";"
Set rstT3 = db.OpenRecordset(strSql_A)

'check for empty recordset
If Not rstT3.BOF And Not rstT3.EOF Then
rstT3.MoveLast
rstT3.MoveFirst

Do While Not rstT3.EOF
'save PK
IngT3PK = rstT3!IRF

'add new record

With rstT3A
.AddNew
!TDPK = IngT2NewFK
!RawCode = Nz(rstT3!RawCode, "")
!Unit = Nz(rstT3!Unit, "")
!PQty = Nz(rstT3!PQty, "")
'etc for other fields.
.Update
intRC_CA = intRC_CA + 1

'Save the primary key value, to use as the foreign key for the related records.

.Bookmark = .LastModified
IngT3NewFK = !IRF
End With

'insert record
 
 db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError


intRC_CA = intRC_CA + 1

rstT3.MoveNext
Loop
rstT3.Close
rstT3A.Close
End If
rstT2.MoveNext
Loop
rstT2.Close
rstT2A.Close
End If
End If

'Display the new duplicate.
 Me.FFP_PHIPLog.Visible = True
 Me.Label186.Visible = True
 Me.Label193.Visible = True
 Me.Label200.Visible = True
 Me.TrialDate.Locked = False
 Me.TrialBy.Locked = False
 Me.QC.Locked = False
 Me.TrialDate.Value = Null
 Me.TrialBy.Value = Null
 Me.QC.Value = Null

'tell me when done
msg = intRC_CD & " record added to TRD_RDTrial"
msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
msg = msg & intRC_CS & " record(s) added to TRD_RDLOG"
msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
msg = msg & intRC_CA & " record(s) added to TFP_PHIPDTL"
msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
msg = msg & "Total records added = " & intRC_CD + intRC_CS + intRC_CA
MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code to achieve this by clicking a button on the main form.
The current record and all child records and child records of these will be copied in a snap to a new main record with child and childchild records, and the form will display this:

```vb
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstAdd      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstSub      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstSubAdd   As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld         As DAO.Field
    Dim Count       As Integer
    Dim CountSub    As Integer
    Dim Item        As Integer
    Dim ItemSub     As Integer
    Dim Bookmark    As Variant
    Dim OldId       As Long
    Dim NewId       As Long
    Dim NewSubId    As Long
    
    ' Copy parent record.
    Set rstAdd = Me.RecordsetClone
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone
    
    ' Move to current record.
    rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    OldId = rst!Id.Value
    With rstAdd
        .AddNew
        For Each fld In .Fields
            With fld
                If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                    ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                Else
                    .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                End If
            End With
        Next
        .Update
        ' Pick Id of the new record.
        .MoveLast
        NewId = !Id.Value
    End With
    ' Store location of new record.
    Bookmark = rstAdd.Bookmark
    
    ' Copy child records.
    ' If a subform is present:
    Set rstAdd = Me!subChild.Form.RecordsetClone
    ' If a subform is not present, retrieve records from the child table:
'    Set rstAdd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblChild Where FK = " & OldId & "")
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

    If rstAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rstAdd.MoveLast
        rstAdd.MoveFirst
    End If
    Count = rstAdd.RecordCount
    For Item = 1 To Count
        With rstAdd
            .AddNew
            For Each fld In .Fields
                With fld
                    If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                        ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                    ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                        ' Skip master/child field.
                        .Value = NewId
                    Else
                        .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            .Update
            ' Pick Id of the new record.
            .MoveLast
            NewSubId = !Id.Value
        End With
        
        ' Copy childchild records.
        Set rstSubAdd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblChildChild Where FK = " & rst!Id.Value & "")
        Set rstSub = rstSubAdd.Clone
        
        If rstSubAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
            rstSubAdd.MoveLast
            rstSubAdd.MoveFirst
        End If
        CountSub = rstSubAdd.RecordCount
        For ItemSub = 1 To CountSub
            With rstSubAdd
                .AddNew
                For Each fld In .Fields
                    With fld
                        If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                            ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                        ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                            ' Skip master/child field.
                            .Value = NewSubId
                        Else
                            .Value = rstSub.Fields(.Name).Value
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
                .Update
            End With
            rstSub.MoveNext
        Next
        
        rst.MoveNext
    Next
    rstSub.Close
    rstSubAdd.Close
    rst.Close
    rstAdd.Close
    
    ' Move to the new recordcopy.
    Me.Bookmark = Bookmark
    
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rstAdd = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

The main challenge is, that while all child records are present in the subform, only one set of subchild records will be present. Thus, the subchild records must be retrieved from the subchild table/query, here named *tblChildChild*.

Also, primary key fields and foreign key fields are named **Id** and **FK** respectively. Adjust as needed.

**To copy a single set of child-childchild records:**

```vb
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstAdd      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld         As DAO.Field
    Dim Bookmark    As Variant
    Dim Bookmark2   As Variant
    Dim Bookmark3   As Variant
    Dim NewId       As Long
    Dim NewSubId    As Long

    ' Record current bookmarks of child and subchild.
    Bookmark2 = Me!subChild.Form.Bookmark
    Bookmark3 = Me!subChild.Form!subChildChild.Form.Bookmark
    
    ' Copy parent record.
    Set rstAdd = Me.RecordsetClone
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

    ' Move to current parent record.
    rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    With rstAdd
        .AddNew
        For Each fld In .Fields
            With fld
                If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                    ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                Else
                    .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                End If
            End With
        Next
        .Update
        ' Pick Id of the new record.
        .MoveLast
        NewId = !Id.Value
    End With
    ' Store location of the new parent record.
    Bookmark = rstAdd.Bookmark
   
    ' Copy child record.
    Set rstAdd = Me!subChild.Form.RecordsetClone
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone
    
    If rstAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ' Move to current child record.
        rst.Bookmark = Bookmark2
        With rstAdd
            .AddNew
            For Each fld In .Fields
                With fld
                    If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                        ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                    ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                        ' Skip master/child field.
                        .Value = NewId
                    Else
                        .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            .Update
            ' Pick Id of the new record.
            .MoveLast
            NewSubId = !Id.Value
        End With

        ' Reposition child form.
        Me!subChild.Form.Bookmark = Bookmark2
        ' Copy child child record.
        Set rstAdd = Me!subChild.Form!subChildChild.Form.RecordsetClone
        Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

        If rstAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
            ' Move to current child child record.
            rst.Bookmark = Bookmark3
            With rstAdd
                .AddNew
                For Each fld In .Fields
                    With fld
                        If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                            ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                        ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                            ' Skip master/child field.
                            .Value = NewSubId
                        Else
                            .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    End If

    rst.Close
    rstAdd.Close

    ' Move to the new record copy.
    Me.Bookmark = Bookmark

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rstAdd = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

**To copy a single set of parent-child and all childchild records of this:**

```vb
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstAdd      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld         As DAO.Field
    Dim Bookmark    As Variant
    Dim Bookmark2   As Variant
    Dim Count       As Integer
    Dim Item        As Integer
    Dim NewId       As Long
    Dim NewSubId    As Long

    ' Record current bookmark of child.
    Bookmark2 = Me!subChild.Form.Bookmark
    
    ' Copy parent record.
    Set rstAdd = Me.RecordsetClone
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

    ' Move to current parent record.
    rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
    With rstAdd
        .AddNew
        For Each fld In .Fields
            With fld
                If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                    ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                Else
                    .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                End If
            End With
        Next
        .Update
        ' Pick Id of the new record.
        .MoveLast
        NewId = !ID.Value
    End With
    ' Store location of the new parent record.
    Bookmark = rstAdd.Bookmark
   
    ' Copy child record.
    Set rstAdd = Me!subChild.Form.RecordsetClone
    Set rst = rstAdd.Clone
    
    If rstAdd.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ' Move to current child record.
        rst.Bookmark = Bookmark2
        With rstAdd
            .AddNew
            For Each fld In .Fields
                With fld
                    If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                        ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                    ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                        ' Skip master/child field.
                        .Value = NewId
                    Else
                        .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            .Update
            ' Pick Id of the new record.
            .MoveLast
            NewSubId = !ID.Value
        End With

        ' Reposition child form.
        Me!subChild.Form.Bookmark = Bookmark2
        ' Copy child child records.
        Set rstAdd = Me!subChild.Form!subChildChild.Form.RecordsetClone
        Set rst = rstAdd.Clone

        If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
            rst.MoveLast
            rst.MoveFirst
        End If
        Count = rst.RecordCount
        For Item = 1 To Count
            With rstAdd
                .AddNew
                For Each fld In .Fields
                    With fld
                        If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                            ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                        ElseIf .Name = "FK" Then
                            ' Skip master/child field.
                            .Value = NewSubId
                        Else
                            .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
                .Update
            End With
            rst.MoveNext
        Next
    End If

    rst.Close
    rstAdd.Close

    ' Move to the new record copy.
    Me.Bookmark = Bookmark

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rstAdd = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I adjust code when i click button appear run time error 3164, and mark this code with yellow .Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value under ' Copy parent record. thanks

Comment: Check the error description and the name of the field. You probably will have to exclude that field.

Comment: i think i am near to my goal, i change "If .Attributes and dbAutoIncrField Then" (First one under copy main form record) to "If .Attributes + dbAutoIncrField Then" when i click button main form give new PK but main form fields not copied, all recordset in child form copied and childchild reocrdset copied.
I need your help in copy main form records and i need to copy childform records only record i see on childform not all recordset if i see child form reocrd no 2 and recordset contain 10 reocrds i want copy no 2 only with its reocrds in childchild table , thank you alot for your effort

Comment: That modification won't work. The code I posted is validated. The issue may be another field that can't be copied.

Comment: You are right , i forgot i have multivalued field in main form table i excluded and its work

Comment: Dear Gustav , i need your support in 2 issues with this code 
1- when i click duplicate button first record in main form duplicated , all related child records duplicated and all related chilcchild records duplicated, what i need duplicate only records appears in form in main form, child form and childchild form what i need modified in this fantastic code to perform this . thanks

Comment: second issue when i duplicate records its take new PK when i reduplicate duplicated records childchild records not duplicated and appear in childchild form any ideas about this. thanks

Comment: First task: See extended answer, please. Second task: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: For first task sorry i don't understand where is extended answer

Comment: for second task i duplicate reocrd let say PK in main form 1 after duplicate all related records duplicated successfully and PK in main form become 100, if i want to duplicate main form PK 100 duplicate success with child records onlu and childchild records not exist , childchild for is empty  thats all . thanks

Comment: _where is extended answer_ - the second code block.

Comment: Dear Gustav, I try your code to copy a single  child_childchild records. its works fine when duplicate main form records, but not work with child records then give error with this line '.Value = rst.Fields(.Name).Value' and runtime error 3164 , as you learned me i checked records type in child table and form i don't found multivalued records , only PK for child table , long text for notes , numbers and texts, i try exclude child pk and notes field but same error occurred , any ideas for that . thanks alot

Comment: When it stops at that line, you have the name of the field. Exclude that (or those) until success. Then double-check the values of the offending field(s). And/or, after having create the copy of the parent record, manually copy the child record, and then the childchild record. That should highligt any error value.

Comment: Dear Gustav, i did as your advice its work with main and child form but childchild records not duplicate , there error in **.update** (after next under **' Move to current child child record.**) with runtime Error 3201: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in the table (table for main form). what i have to do thanks

Comment: All tables are supposed to have an AutoNumber ID. The new IDs will be picked up by `NewId` and `NewSubId`. So, double-check that and, again, do a manual append of the records to watch potential errors.

Comment: Dear Gustav, i did as your advice, now main form duplicated, child form duplicated successfully and childchild form duplicate only first row . what i need to do to duplicate all childchild form rows. Thanks

Comment: But you wrote: _what i need duplicate only records appears in form in main form, child form and childchild form_. Isn't that "one record from each form/childform/childchildform"?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding from my side, childchild form contain many rows 1:M(many side).Thanks

Comment: But so does the child form, or?

Comment: child form works fine, i need to select that one record appear in form but chilchild form has many rows something like recipe name(child form) and ingredients with quantities (childchild form)

Comment: OK. Answer has been extended. See third code block, please.

Comment: It's works like a charm GUSTAV

Comment: Great! You may upvote my answer, if you feel so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and patient . I am grateful for you . Because your efforts we have a full reference for duplication records via 3 levels deep

Comment: For upvote sure i want, i trying to do that many times but Site inform me because I am new user I need 15 reputation first to do that but I sorting your answer as trending